# Escape sequence to set cursor hollow?

Tags: vim, terminal, xterm, ansi-escape

I'm using xterm. If the xterm window loses the focus the text cursor becomes hollow. I want to use a hollow cursor as cursor form when vim switches from insert into normal mode. Therefore I need the escape sequence to change the cursor from block into hollow.

Answer (score 1):

`xterm` does not do that.  It (currently) provides distinguishable combinations of these (using the [`DECSCUSR` control sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q.1D81)):

- (solid) block
- underline (rather than block)
- vertical bar (rather than block or underline)
- blinking (combined with any of the above)

Empty blocks denote, as you have observed, the fact that `xterm` no longer has the focus.

There is no control sequence which will produce an empty block.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: The hollow (empty) block cursor is no shape which the user can use simply via a control sequence but is created from xterm internally when losing the focus.